# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCustomTwilioVideoView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, twilio, webrtc

I want to implement twilio-video in react-native with expo, getting this error, and app is not running.

[image]

I installed the package, followed guide also tried to create something like that:

[image]

nothing worked. maybe this is simple question.